# Fourier series for rectangular wave incorrect, why?

Tags: fourier-analysis

I'm trying to get the fourier series function(s) to work for a square wave with duty cycles other than 50% ie rectangular wave.

```
squareWave[t_, period_, duty_] := UnitBox[Mod[t/period, 1.]/(2. duty)]    
xx[t_] := squareWave[t, 10, 0.8]    
Plot[xx[t], {t, -10, 10}, Background -> Gray]
curvexx = FourierTrigSeries[xx[t], t, 10];  
Plot[curvexx, {t, -10, 10}, Background -> Gray]
```

that's my code, set up squarewave, check by plotting (alright so far), take fourier series, check by plotting and it's wrong but why where did I go wrong?

Comment: Your code is incomplete.  `squareWave` is not defined.  Please post complete code: it should be possible to just copy and paste to test it.

Comment: @Öskå Maybe.  But that's not what the OP wrote.  Not posting complete code and not posting the same code that produced the error already wastes too much time on this site.

Comment: forgot to paste squareWave[t_, period_, duty_] := UnitBox[Mod[t/period, 1.]/(2. duty)] but really it aint a crime

Comment: @user15970 - `FourierTrigSeries` doesn't accept the `FourierParameters`-Option. Eliminate that and you get at least a nice image :)

Comment: @eldo Actually it does.  The red colouring is not correct.

Comment: @user15970 Please explain what result you get, what result you expect, and why you think that the result you get is incorrect.  You may be looking for `FourierParameters -> {1, Pi/5}`.  Why did you choose `FourierParameters -> {1, π/2}`?

Comment: okay I just got rid of FourierParameters

Comment: its wrong because the curvexx plot is not the same period as the xx[t] plot

Comment: @user15970 Please read the documentation of `FourierTrigSeries` carefully, especially under the Details section where it is precisely defined what this function does, and how `FourierParameters` affect the result.  You'll see that your choice of `FourierParameters` must match the period.

Comment: okay with FourierParameters -> {1, Pi/10} its okay ie sorted without as edited above its wrong

Comment: curvexx = 
  FourierTrigSeries[xx[t], t, 20, FourierParameters -> {1, Pi/10}];
Plot[curvexx, {t, -10, 10}, Background -> Gray] does the trick many thanks to Szabolcs

Comment: @user15970 `FourierTrigSeries` essentially truncates the function to the interval $(-\pi, \pi)$.  By using `FourierParameters -> {1, Pi/5}` this is extended to $(-5, 5)$.  Just make sure the interval width is equal to the period (or possibly an integer multiple of it).  My original suggestion of `Pi/10` makes it 2x larger, so `Pi/5` is better.

Answer (score 7):

`FourierTrigSeries` essentially truncates the domain of the function to the interval $(-\pi,\pi)$. In other words, it assumes that the period of the function is $2\pi$.  If this is not the case, you need to use `FourierParameters` to change this interval.  `FourierParameters -> {1,b}` uses $(-\pi/b, \pi/b)$, so for a function of period `p` you need to use `FourierParameters -> {1, 2Pi/p}`, i.e. in your case use `FourierParameters -> {1,Pi/5}`.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not well-versed in Fourier analysis, but your problem seems to stem from the choice of period. `FourierTrigSeries` appears to be assuming a period of 2 π

```
squareWave[period_, duty_] := UnitBox[Mod[t/period, 1.]/(2. duty)]
xx[t_] := squareWave[2 Pi, 0.8]
Plot[xx[t], {t, -10, 10}]
curvexx = FourierTrigSeries[xx[t], t, 8];
Plot[curvexx, {t, -10, 10}]
```

[image: square]

[image: approx]

Comment: there is an option `FourierParameters` to modify the period.